# How to create a slider that changes numeric values inside two input boxes representing time

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a slider that changes the value of two input boxes that represent time.

Please allow me to use a picture as an example:

[image]

In the above photo, you can see one slider for each pair of input-boxes.

As the slider moves from left to right, numeric values inside each input box decreases. These input boxes represent time (minute and second, respectively).

Can you please help me make this? This is what I've tried thus far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<label>One Input Box</label><br>
<input id="A"
       type="number"
       class="occupied"
       required=""
       min="1"
       max="100"
       onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 100){ this.value = 100; return false; }"
>
<br>
<input id="MDLslider" class="occupied" type="range" min="0" max="340" oninput="A.value=MDLslider.value"/>
<br>
<br>
<br>


<label>Two Input Boxes for Time?</label><br>
<input id="D"
       type="number"
       class="occupied"
       placeholder="Minutes"
       required=""
       min="1"
       max="59"
       onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 59){ this.value = 59; return false; }"
>
<input id="E"
       type="number"
       class="occupied"
       placeholder="Seconds"
       required=""
       min="1"
       max="59"
       onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 59){ this.value = 59; return false; }"
>
<input id="TIMEslider" class="occupied" type="range" min="0" max="59" oninput="D.value=TIMEslider.value"/>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

measuring the slider value as seconds, you can divide by 60 for the minute and get the modulus for the seconds

```js
document.querySelector('#TIMEslider').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  let mins = e.target.value / 60;
  let xtra = e.target.value % 60
  document.querySelector('#D').value = Math.floor(mins);
  document.querySelector('#E').value = Math.floor(xtra);
})
```

```html
  <label>One Input Box</label><br>
  <input id="A" type="number" class="occupied" required="" min="1" max="100" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 100){ this.value = 100; return false; }">
  <br>
  <input id="MDLslider" class="occupied" type="range" min="0" max="340" oninput="A.value=MDLslider.value" />
  <br>
  <label>Two Input Boxes for Time?</label><br>
  <input id="D" type="number" class="occupied" placeholder="Minutes" required="" min="1" max="59" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 59){ this.value = 59; return false; }">
  <input id="E" type="number" class="occupied" placeholder="Seconds" required="" min="1" max="59" onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 59){ this.value = 59; return false; }">
  <input id="TIMEslider" class="occupied" type="range" min="0" max="600" />
```